# Implement serialPort.write in Python

Tags: python, serial-port

In my javascript code I turn the `arudino` lights on like following:

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;
serialPort.write("1", function(err, results)
```

How can I implement this method in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import serial
port,baud = "/dev/ttyUSB0",9600 #just an example (linux)
port,baud = "COM5",9600 #just an example (win)
ser = serial.serial(port,baud,timeout=1)
ser.write("1")
print "RESP 1:",ser.read(10000)
ser.write("2")
print "RESP 2:",ser.read(10000)
```

I guess .... it looks like you just want to send "1" to a serialport followed by "2" ...